# rails 3.2: file_tag with default FILE selected for importing data from it if no file selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I am working with csv/excel import feature with `roo gem`. And my working piece of code is:

```
<h2>Import Excel File</h2>
<%= form_tag import_rows_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import", :class => 'gen-btn' %>
<% end %>
```

**New Feature**

I want to set default file in `file_field_tag`, so that, if user do not select csv/excel file, then I want to import data from that `default file (/home/try_this.xlsx)`.

***I tried:***

```
<%= file_field_tag :file, value: "/home/try_this.xlsx" %>
```

but clicking in import button without selecting csv/excel file is giving `ERRORS: File not found!` error

What I am missing here?? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The http protocol does not allow for pre-selected files. You need to select it by hand, it is a severe security issue.

Imagine a page asking to submit a file by default and then, `onload=this.form.submit()`... There goes your file and you know nothing of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing wrong here. Yep,as stavros suggested, we can't pre-select files, that is a security reason.

I was trying to resolve this way in watir automation testing, but I was doing wrong. Instead we have a `set()` method available in watir, which can set required file path and that is the solution for my problem.

`Watir automation test`

```
@browser.file_field(:name, "file").set("/home/try_this.xlsx")
```

The best place to stor this file is our project directory and we can access it like:

```
@browser.file_field(:name, "file").set("#{Dir.pwd}/try_this.xlsx")
```

Thanks